# How to detect Title and Subtitles in UIWebview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mobile-safari

How can one obtain the title of an webpage shown in UIWebview?

In addition, are there any way of detecting subtitles within the text in a block of text in UIWebview?

Alternatively, are there any way of identifying if a string is bold/italic/underlined? Or is that not stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript

For the first question

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"title %@",[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"]);
}
```